# What's wrong with pine tree?

Tags: indoors, plant-care, tree-care, transplanting, pines

I’m updating the thread to post a recent picture of the pine tree. As you can see, the tree’s looking worse. I moved it to the balcony so it would receive more sun, but it hasn’t helped:

[image]

This is the original thread:
.…….…….…….…….……

I bought this pine tree in November. In mid-February I changed the *weird* soil it came with (it was looking a bit sick) and it got healthier.

Lately, it's been looking sick again. I'm including some pictures.

What can I do to improve the plant's health? Should it be outside? We're in the Caribbean.

Thanks.

Edit:
Just wanted to clarify that the white dots all over the tree is glitter that the store added to it to make it look more like a *Christmas* tree. Sorry for the confusion.

[image][image][image]

Comment: What are the white dots all over the branches - I can't tell what they are even under magnification?

Comment: I am not sure if this a pinus species or a Norfolk island pine with a bad case of spider mites

Comment: Guttation? Is that sap? Does the pot have drainage? Looks like a Norfolk to me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The white dots is glitter that the store added to make it look like a Christmas tree.

Comment: Glitter? How is it glued on? spray adhesive may be blocking some stomata. I'd take the poor tree outside and hose the glitter off. That'll help it breathe.

Comment: I bought it at Home Depot and it had the glitter.

Comment: It seems to be glued on. I tried hosing the glitter off but the glitter’s still there, very little came off.

Comment: @rbhat So they did something evil to get it on there. Since you can't very well dip the tree in paint thinner, just be nice to it. Maybe needle growth or sun/wind exposure will dislodge the stuff, and you'll have a happy plant.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general steps you can take:

Pine tree's like full sun so keep it near a window where it will have a consistent source of natural light. They like moist soil but not wet soil. What I mean is they desire constant moisture but take care not to swamp them out. One trick for consistent growth is to rotate the plant every other day. It will help to ensure that all portions of growth are receiving and equal amount of sunlight. Be sure to prune it consistently by removing dead old-growth as needed. Also, don't be afraid to feed the plant with a quality organic (indoor plant) fertilizer.

EDIT (additional information): Pine's like the weather to stay in between 50-70° F or (10-20 °C) and night time temperatures shouldn't drop below 40° F (4° C). If the species you have was harvested locally then it stands to reason that it could live outside on your terrace.

Comment: Should I move it to an outdoor (no roof) terrace where it will get direct sun? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Norfork Island pines do not like to be wet , I think that was the problem. Not expensive , I suggest dumping it and buy a new one next Christmas and don't give as much water . I had the other problem , after a couple years it got to big for the space ( and still had some Christmas glitter), I gave it away and may get another.